# Scheduling twitter status update via api

Tags: c#, twitter

I've seen how to do this via the Facebook API but not found anything out yet about Twitter. Is it possible to schedule a Twitter status update so that it doesn't get sent immediately?

Comment: The easiest option is to just delay the processing of the queue message that results in the sending of the twitter API call (e.g. initialVisibilityDelay property in Azure Queues). This obviously assumes that you are sending your social stuff via sort sort of message queue but being such as conscientious developer, know that you are Simon :-)

Comment: Cheers Paul (had to do some sleuthing to work that one out!). Good shout on the queue front. Obviously I was just coming around to that idea :) I'm hosting via AppHarbor, so IronMQ looks to be the way forward